# Create records with cyclic dependencies?

Tags: purescript

In purescript, records with a cyclic dependency can be declared as follows

```
  newtype User = User
  { name :: String
  , organization :: Organization
  }

  newtype Organization = Organization
  { name :: String
  , users :: List User
  }
```

But I haven't figured out how to actually create instances in purescript. In F#, instances can be created as follows.

```
let rec pam = { name = "Pamela"; organization = fed }
and jill = { name = "Jillian"; organization = fed }
and fed = { name = "Federal Reserve"; users = [pam;jill] }
```

I always get a value of pam is undefined. Maybe using the fix function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do this in PureScript without making some part of the structure lazy:

```
import Data.Lazy (Lazy, defer)

newtype User = User
  { name :: String
  , organization :: Lazy Organization
  }

newtype Organization = Organization
  { name :: String
  , users :: Array User
  }

fed :: Organization
fed =
  Organization
    { name: "Federal Reserve"
    , users:
        [ User { name: "Pamela", organization: defer \_ -> fed }
        , User { name: "Jillian", organization: defer \_ -> fed }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! This does what I need.

Comment: Ah great, wasn't sure if that was going to be acceptable for your use case!